# Windows 7 on Mac Book Pro

Tags: windows-7

I want to take a screen grab on a mac book pro running windows 7 - is there a short cut? I'd like to set a Fn key - how do I do this?

cheers

Gav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the print screen key to do this.  An alternative would be to use the [Snipping Tool to capture a screen shot](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots).

> Open Snipping Tool by clicking the
>   Start button. In the search box, type
>   Snipping Tool, and then, in the list
>   of results, click Snipping Tool.

[image]

If you want to remap a function key to be the print screen key, check out this [howtogeek page on using SharpKeys](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/).

Comment: Hi Mark - thanks, I just discovered this just before I got your reply, but very useful anyway. Why did it have to be named something else? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows world <kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> is simply <kbd>F13</kbd> with a different label.

The <kbd>F13</kbd> key on your Mac keyboard should work!

Should be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> on a MacBook Pro

Another one to try, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> may also work

A further option would be to use the Windows Accessibility On-Screen Keyboard's <kbd>psc</kbd> button

Comment: There is no F13 key on a Macbook pro keyboard.

Comment: Shift F1 is apparently the same (I don't have one to test this on)

Answer (score 1):

Please note - Shevek's answer is incorrect!

As per [Apple's support site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1220), the correct key combination for PrtScr on the MacBook Pro is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend [PrtScr](http://www.fiastarta.com/PrtScr/) if you want a really neat print screen tool for windows or if you want the ability to upload like how [Grabup](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/04/15/grabup/) works on the Mac you could use [ScreenSnapr](http://screensnapr.com/) however I think Grabup have a windows client out now...